# How to read a file from the USB storage on Android with dotnet MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, xamarin.android, maui

How can I read a file from external USB storage on an Android device using the .Net MAUI Framework?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=windows

Answer (score 0):

The reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage?tabs=windows) mentions Xamarin, but the idea is the same.

You can use the standard .NET APIs as mentioned in this quote from the documentation:

> Once a Xamarin.Android app has obtained the full path to a file, it should utilize any of the standard .NET APIs for creating, reading, writing, or deleting files. This maximizes the amount of cross platform compatible code for an app.

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/#reading-or-writing-to-files-on-internal-storage) is another Xamarin link, but the idea is the same:

> Any of the C# APIs for writing to a file are sufficient; all that is necessary is to get the path to the file that is in the directory allocated to the application. It is strongly recommended that the async versions of the .NET APIs are used to minimize any issues that may be associate with file access blocking the main thread.